# JSF Resources - Remove query string recommendation page speed

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

According to page speed my JSF resources would benefit from removing query strings:

> Remove query strings from static resources
>
> Enabling public caching in the HTTP headers for static resources
>   allows the browser to download resources from a nearby proxy server,
>   rather than from a remote origin server.

https://www.medexpress.co.uk/javax.faces.resource/style.css.xhtml?ln=css&v=1_2

It also reports:

> Leverage browser caching
>
> Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static
>   resources, instructs the browser to load previously downloaded
>   resources from local disk, rather than over the network.

How can I make JSF resources conform to page speed suggestions?

Comment: I've amended my question.

Comment: @codyLine I used the pagespeed module with apache and it takes care of this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the mod_pagespeed module with Apache.
This takes care of this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But this is for the apache server! JSF app cannot run on apache, only on a j2ee application server!

Comment: @codyLine: of course Java EE cannot run on Apache HTTP. But you can put Apache HTTP as a proxy in front of a Java EE application server. It can then take care of many low level HTTP things such as cacheenable, proxypassing, URL rewriting, showing maintenance screen when appserver is down, etc.

Comment: Thank you @BalusC! I wasn't aware of it. Actually I'm using Omnifaces for 2 years now and for many performance purposes. Are you planing to add such a feature to Omnifaces? Is it possible, to achieve this in Glassfish (is the application server I'm using)? Should I better post a new Thread?! Sorry